# How to draw a Line above an QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qt4

actually i'm programming a scale moving "inside" a QGraphicsScene:

```
QPixmap scale("./images/skala.xpm");
pScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
Label = new QGraphicsView();
pScene->addPixmap(scale);
pScene->setSceneRect(ScalePos_X, ScalePos_Y, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight);
Label->setScene(pScene);
Label->show();
```

The moving is done via `setSceneRect()`.

Now i want to draw a fixed middle-line marking the middle of the scale (middle of pScene).
I can draw a line inside QGraphicsScene, but this line is moving while moving the scene (logically)

Is it possible to draw somehow a line ABOVE QGraphicsScene?

Comment: You can install an event filter on the `QGraphicsView` object, intercept paint events and paint additional line using `QPainter`. Alternatively, you can subclass `QGraphicsView` and reimplement its `paintEvent`.

Comment: you can draw a line using QGraphicsLineItem and set the flag of the item ass as QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum .